# Rails- Merge a find with 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I want to build a rails request with 2 models.
I think it's quite simple, but I don't want to do a loop myself.

I'm in my country model:

```
  def self.find_for_user(user_id)
    wines = Wine.where("user_id = ?", user_id).group(:country_id)

    where("countries.id IN ?", wines.map())
  end
```

I want to get all countries depending the first request (the wines grouped by countries, I just need the countries)

I think I can do this in a single line where I put map() or another instruction. I just need to get all country_id fields for wines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you've got an association set up between wines and country (ie. `has_many :wines` in country.rb), I think this is what you're looking for:

```
def self.find_for_user(user_id)
  joins(:wines).where('wines.user_id = ?', user_id).uniq
end
```

Comment: This is perfect and looks like more "rails". :) Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is all countries that have wine for a specific user, you can do that in SQL:

```
where("countries.id in (select country_id from wines where wines.user_id = ?)", user_id)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But I think I will use the code of Chris. I don't know which one takes less resources.